# Skylake iGPUs support hardware accelerated decoding of most video formats. What libraries do I need to enable them in Chrome and Totem?

Tags: google-chrome, video, intel-graphics, codecs, totem

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics?wprov=sfsi1), Skylake iGPUs support hardware accelerated decoding of H.265/HEVC,  H.264/MPEG-4 AVC, MPEG-2, VC-1, WMV9, JPEG/MJPEG and VP9. What packages do I need to install to enable hardware accelerated decoding of these formats in Totem and Chrome (looks like Firefox doesn't support hardware accelerated decoding at all).

Comment: don't use chrome so only partial, for totem install `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` Works fine though atm vp9 hwdec is not supported in libva  though it seems it should. Have a bug here, note that lack of support extends to all media players, not just gstreamer ones. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-vaapi-driver/+bug/1591714

Comment: @doug Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to enable hardware acceleration (with the exception of VP9) for Firefox (or any other browsers)? Looks like FF does not support hardware accelerated playback of videos at all.

Comment: Also how can I be sure that Totem is using VAAPI and not VDAPU? My desktop only has the integrated Skylake GPU. Can I uninstall `*vdpau*` packages?